# Riddle about number of digits in an interval.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> What digit is the most frequent between the numbers 1 and 1,000
> (inclusive)?

Hey I found this riddle and I was wondering if there is any pattern that I could use so I don't have to calculate it manually haha :)

Comment: In numbers $1-999$ there should be same number of digits from $1$ to $9$ (can you see why)? So the $1000$ will just make one more occurrence of digit $1$. Digit $0$ is not interesting since it is not allowed as left-most digits (I assume), so its occurence will be less than other digits.

Comment: The last digit, if it appears, you should be able to recognize is just as often one digit as any other.  The second to last digit, you should be able to recognize is just as often one digit as any other.  The exceptions being $0$ was not the last digit in a one-digit number and so is underrepresented and the digit $1$ is the only number who is the first digit in a 4-digit number since we stopped at $1000$ and so is overrepresented.

Comment: Nice thanks I get it now! :))